# How to set all checkboxes checked by default if dropdown is closed?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [Material UI multiple select](https://%20%20%20%20//console.log(%22value%22,%20value%5Bvalue.length%20-%201%5D);) and my goal is to set all checkboxes checked, including the `All`, if nothing is checked  after closing the dropdown.
 So if nothing is selected and dropdown is closed, I want to have all checkboxes checked.
I have created a `boolean` state called `open` which triggers if the dropdown closes. 
 I have `isAllSelected` boolean which also turns to true if all are selected. So this is the way I'm trying to implement via the booleans, but something doesn't work.
[Demo sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-multiple-select-with-select-all-option-forked2-9i35xy?file=/src/App.js:0-2740) and Code example below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import { MenuProps, useStyles, options } from "./utils";

function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(options);
  const isAllSelected =
    options.length > 0 && selected.length === options.length;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (value[value.length - 1] === "all" && open) {
      setSelected(selected.length === options.length ? [] : options);
      return;
    }
    setSelected(value);
  };
  console.log("open", open);
  console.log("isAllSelected", isAllSelected);

  return (
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <InputLabel id="mutiple-select-label">Multiple Select</InputLabel>
      <Select
        open={open}
        onOpen={handleOpen}
        onClose={handleClose}
        labelId="mutiple-select-label"
        multiple
        value={selected}
        onChange={handleChange}
        renderValue={(selected) =>
          !isAllSelected ? selected.join(", ") : "alle"
        }
        MenuProps={MenuProps}
      >
        <MenuItem
          value="all"
          classes={{
            root: isAllSelected ? classes.selectedAll : ""
          }}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Checkbox
              //defaultChecked={!isAllSelected}
              classes={{ indeterminate: classes.indeterminateColor }}
              checked={!isAllSelected && !open}
              indeterminate={
                selected.length > 0 && selected.length < options.length
              }
            />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText
            classes={{ primary: classes.selectAllText }}
            primary="Select All"
          />
        </MenuItem>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Checkbox
                //defaultChecked
                checked={
                  !isAllSelected && !open ? true : selected.indexOf(option) > -1
                }
              />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={option} />
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is `handleClose` method not what it sounds-like? I tried running the sandbox & added an `alert` to that method & it is displayed when the dropdown closes. If it is correct, then one simply needs to check the array and if none-selected, then select all. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hey @jsN00b could you please, provide a link, so that it makes more sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the state for the checkbox and once you change it for default settings you can use `defaultChecked`

```
<input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.state.chkbox} onChange={this.handleChangeChk} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, updating the setter value via useEffect.
I am checking if the dropdown is closed and nothing is checked/selected, then wrap all elements in the `selected` array.

Code and [demo sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-multiple-select-with-select-all-option-forked2-9i35xy?file=/src/App.js:4314-4451)

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    if (selected.length < 1 && !open) {
      setSelected(options);
    }
  }, [open, isAllSelected, selected]);
```